# Knitr ignoring width and out.width options

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have a R Markdown that I knit to html from within RStudio. I can use fig.width and fig.height to adjust the resolution of my plots but I can't seem to widen the page output so that text output doesn't wrap or so that the plots appear physically larger. I have tried:

````
```{r}
options(width=2000)
```
````

and

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_knit$set(width=2000)
```
````

and

````
```{r,out.width=2000}
```
````

The output page width never changes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This Rmd file produces different plot sizes:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "6 - 10 - 2015"
output: html_document
---
I have a R Markdown that I knit to html from within RStudio. I can use fig.width and fig.height to adjust the resolution of my plots but I can't seem to widen the page output so that text output doesn't wrap or so that the plots appear physically larger. I have tried:

```{r}
options(width=2000)
```
and

```{r}
knitr::opts_knit$set(width=2000)
plot(cars)
```
and

```{r,out.width=2000}
#using out.width=2000
plot(cars)
```
or
```{r,fig.width=4}
#using fig.width=4
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Yes that changes the figure size but it is still limited to the page size. I am trying to increase the page size I guess. Increasing the fig.width work until fig.width==\linewidth then the output image just gets resized but not physically bigger. I can set fig.width=2000 and it will be blury and I will still have to squint to make out small text.